# Kubernetes - grant full access to all namespaces matching prefix or regex

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, rbac

I am planning to deploy review-apps to kubernetes using namespaces. That is, my CI generates a random ID, I build a namespace from this like `review-app-xxx` and inside I'm deploying several helm charts.

How can I easily give access to all those namespaces to a group of people ?

Concrete example: assume I have several of those namespaces

- `review-app-aaaa`
- `review-app-bbbb`
- `review-app-cccc`

What is the most simple way to give full access to those namespaces for a user belonging to group `tech:dev` ?

EDIT:

The non-dry way to think about it is to have one roleBinding per namespace like this

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: namespace-full-access-cluster-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]

---

kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: full-access-staging-namespace-for-devs
  namespace: review-app-aaaa
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: devs
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: namespace-full-access-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

but is there a way to dry this ?

Comment: Have you considered using RBAC (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision, I was actually looking for a way to implement this using kubernetes rbac (I added the tag) the problem is I don't think we can have wildcard names in namespaces so I'm not sure whether this can be done at all
(I mean there's the non-dry way of adding one rolebinding per namespace, but this is what I wanted to avoid). I have added this to my question

Comment: Gotch ya, looks like there is no way to implement it using regex etc. Your presented non-dry way seems to be just fine, alternatively you can use a command line as presented in https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-rolebinding. Also, please note that it might be a good idea to create custom cluster roles to limit the given access to the lowest needed.

Comment: do you need to create rolebinding in multiple namespaces at once. this is still a limitation to create namespaced resources across multiple namespaces. we often get requirements of create same imagepullsecrets in multiple namespaces, and there is no native way to do that.

Comment: you can write a controller that will watch for ns resource and action based on the events